# Can we send data to online excel sheet using python?

Tags: python, excel

I want to send a row of numbers and these should add as a new row in the online excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) library to open & edit an Excel file like this

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

url = '/home/alex/test.xls'

workbook = load_workbook(url)
sheet= workbook .get_sheet_by_name("Sheet name")
sheet.write(0,0,'hello world')
book.save(url)
```

It works with local files but I don't know if you can do that with online files. Maybe with `requests` Python library but we need more information about your **online excel sheet**